# How get all objects from an array of Id's in mongoose with express nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm developing a Chat application where I'm saving the conversation list in the DB like this;

Conversations Collection:

```
{ 
   members: [ "123", "456" ]
   ...rest
}
```

and User Collection:

```
{
   _id: ObjectId( "123" ), name: "anyone"
},
{
   _id: ObjectId( "456" ), name: "someone"
}
```

I want the result to be like:

```
{
   members: [
              {_id: ObjectId( "123" ), name: "anyone"},
              {_id: ObjectId( "456" ), name: someone"}
            ]
}
```

I know aggregation with lookup is the rescue but can't find a way how to fetch all ids from that member's array because in the future it can be 20 to 30 ids. If it is a simple field then I'm able to fetch but with an array, I can't.

I have tried this

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "members",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "members_details"
    }
  }
])
```

but it returns members_details: [ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `members` id is string in conversation collection, you can convert it to object id and the join to users collection,

- `$addFields` to update `members` array
- `$map` to iterate loop of `members` array
- `$toObjectId` to convert string object id type to object id type

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      members: {
        $map: {
          input: "$members",
          in: {
            $toObjectId: "$$this"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "members",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "members"
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QVsV-dnSadb)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following query to accomplish what you want. You'll need to use `$lookup` since you are wanting to gather data from a different collection then the one you are currently querying.

You can check out a [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QL0II1C3Rbf)

Here is an updated [live demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4Cjf3-G9mq)

### Database

```
db={
  "conversations": [
    {
      members: [
        123,
        456
      ]
    }
  ],
  "users": [
    {
      "_id": 123,
      "name": "foo"
    },
    {
      "_id": 456,
      "name": "bar"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Query

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "localField": "members",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "members"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      members: 1
    }
  }
])
```

### Result

```
[
  {
    "members": [
      {
        "_id": 123,
        "name": "foo"
      },
      {
        "_id": 456,
        "name": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

## Update

See new [live demo here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-P1IcxG4JZZ)

### New Query

```
db.conversations.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$members"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",
      "as": "membersFlat",
      "let": {
        memberObjectId: {
          "$toObjectId": "$members"
        }
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $eq: [
                "$$memberObjectId",
                "$_id"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      members: {
        $push: {
          "_id": {
            $first: "$membersFlat._id"
          },
          "name": {
            $first: "$membersFlat.name"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

### New Result

```
[
  {
    "members": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("124578987898787845658574"),
        "name": "foo"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("124578986532124578986532"),
        "name": "bar"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: This will not work because in the users collection _id represents as a ObjectId type not a string. already tried this solution not worked. Anyway thanks

Comment: I have updated your demo check - https://mongoplayground.net/p/bfZENqF8s3c
DB will be like this

Comment: I went ahead and updated to demo again to show how you can use ObjectId. https://mongoplayground.net/p/T4Cjf3-G9mq

Comment: Thanks, @matt but I can't make members array as an ObjectId of the array because it is coming from frontend and directly saved to DB

Comment: Check out the update to my answer. See here for live demo https://mongoplayground.net/p/-P1IcxG4JZZ

Answer (score 0):

You can use a normal `.find()` like this:

```
const members = [
    ObjectId('4ed3ede8844f0f351100000c'),
    ObjectId('4ed3f117a844e0471100000d'), 
    ObjectId('4ed3f18132f50c491100000e')
]

const docs = await model.find({
    '_id': { $in: members }
}).exec()
```

Comment: I want to query on conversation collection and try to get the user object. How a normal find will work?

Comment: sorry, i misunderstood the question

Answer (score 0):

Install [mongoose-autopopulate](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-autopopulate). And in your model code

---

```js
import {Schema, model} from 'mongoose';

const modelSchema = new Schema({
   ...
   chats: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Chat", autopopulate: true}]
})

modelSchema.plugin(require('mongoose-autopopulate'));
...
```